# Pouchdb-find + Cloudant : Error: unknown operator "0" - should be one of

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

Created a json index and tested a query on the cloudant dashboard.

```
{
  "selector": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$and": [
          { "type": { "$eq": "user" }},
          {
            "$or": [
              { "user":         { "$eq": "Elvis" }},
              { "first_name":   { "$eq": "Elvis" }},
              { "middle_name":  { "$eq": "Elvis" }},
              { "last_name":    { "$eq": "Elvis" }}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "$not": {
          "$and": [
            { "type": { "$in": ["follower", "admin"] }},
            { "hive": { "$eq": "8049CF96-A4F2-D2BE-B014-AA4F72642F3F" }},
            { "user": { "$eq": "Elvis" }}
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "fields": [
    "_id",
    "_rev"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "_id": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above works on the dashboard, but when I use it through pouchdb-find, it throws an error as below:

```
Error: unknown operator "0" - should be one of $eq, $lte, $lt, $gt, $gte, $exists, $ne, $in, $nin, $size, $mod, $regex, $elemMatch, $type or $all
Stack trace:
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your example selector with a Cloudant database and I did not get an error:

```
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));

var db = new PouchDB('https://reader.cloudant.com/aaa');
var s = {"selector":{"$and":[{"$and":[{"type":{"$eq":"user"}},{"$or":[{"user":{"$eq":"Elvis"}},{"first_name":{"$eq":"Elvis"}},{"middle_name":{"$eq":"Elvis"}},{"last_name":{"$eq":"Elvis"}}]}]},{"$not":{"$and":[{"type":{"$in":["follower","admin"]}},{"hive":{"$eq":"8049CF96-A4F2-D2BE-B014-AA4F72642F3F"}},{"user":{"$eq":"Elvis"}}]}}]},"fields":["_id","_rev"],"sort":[{"_id":"asc"}]};

db.find(s).then(function(d) {
  console.log(d);
}).catch(function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
```

Please try the above code yourself. For reference, my documents look like this:

```
{
  "type": "user",
  "first_name": "Elvis",
  "middle_name": "",
  "last_name": "Presley",
  "user": "a",
  "hive": "aaa"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Glynn Bird, I added keyword by keyword to my selector and finally as you said the above worked...but now I'm wondering what was wrong in the first place.